# Azure DevOps: How to restrict permissions to boards only?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, devops

I want to add a guest account to my Azure Active Directoy and give it access to an Azure DevOps project. Inside the project the guest should only be allowed to create, edit and delete work items. Basically all the features on boards except administrative work. All other features of DevOps should be restricted.

The problem is, that I can't find a way to create a new group which fits my requirements. As soon as a user should be able to create work items he must be member of the default "Contributor" group. But then he can also create environments for example because there is no way to deny permissions regarding environments inside self defined groups.

Does anybody have an idea how to restrict permissions for a user or a group to only the mentioned board related features?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody have an idea how to restrict permissions for a user or a group to only the mentioned board related features?

Indeed, there is no such group which fits your requirements directly.

As workaround, we could create a new group as member of the `Contributors` group:

[image]

we add this new created group as `Reader` in the **Security** of Environments:

[image]

Then add this new created group to other modules that need to be restricted with same principle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution describes exactly what I did so far. Sad that there is no way to specify the permissions more detailed.

Comment: @Stimmler, Indeed, AFAIK, there is no way to specify the permissions more detailed at this moment. As we know, Azure devops is an integrated CI/CD tool. There are many connections between each module. It is difficult for us to set the permissions of a certain module individually. Personally think your current solution is reasonable.